# Making the one link style appear the same under two different div widths

Tags: html, css

I have taken an anchor tag and styled it to look like a typical button (hardcore stuff!! Lol!), but when I use this button inside a div that's `75%` wide and I do the same but inside a div that's `20%` wide; both buttons sharing the same style don't look the same as one another?

I understand that this is because the padding on my button style is based on the width of its parent and that's why they both look different.

So without creating a new version of my button class every time there's a new width; how can I get around this and make both buttons look the same regardless of parent width?

Please see my js fiddle link for how I've coded this issue so far

https://jsfiddle.net/samuelcrockford/m94myv69/#&togetherjs=bk5j85kNr3

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

"how can I make both buttons look the same regardless of parent width? "

Would it be a problem to define the button width in pixel (px) instead of percent (%) ?

EDIT :
From the comment, here is a way to define a button size in different container.

```
.wide .button {width:20%;}
.small .button {width:50%;}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But I would rather it was a relative unit of measure so the button can adapt more.

Comment: You can then play with css inheritance. So your div width will depend from the parent, without being linked by percentage

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `%` in your padding, instead use `px` to determine the desired padding on buttons output.

Note: Padding will use the space 'minus' the size of the container base on your rule.

Here's the sample:

```
.button {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 6px 12px; // from 10% 5%
  /* over kill just for example */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/imarkdesigns/m94myv69/1/

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I've been doing some reading and I've now found that using rem's works just fine. What are your thoughts on this? Thank you!

Comment: I use "rem" at fonts basically, though some developers use "em & rem" as their main units. Honest to tell, I'm not a fan of these units except for fonts size only :(

Comment: Cool stuff! So do you use pixels for padding on complex nested div's or do you have a different way of approaching the whole thing; Thank you!

Comment: I use "pixel unit" all the time. Sometimes I mixed it with % while using `calc()` to subtract or divide divs in some nested containers. There's a site explain it well all the units including vh, vw and vmin units along with the fallbacks support for backward compatibility.

Comment: Smashing! I will check all of that out. I can't wait to start using viewport units, they look very cool and for the calc I may need to do a little research but thank you for all of your help and for exposing me to new concepts.